# Access Token Expired-Fetching data from Marketo Activities to Salesforce Custom Object Using Batch Class

Tags: salesforce, access-token, marketo

I am fetching data from Marketo Activities to Salesforce Custom Object using Batch Class. My Batch is scheduled to run after every 5 minutes and get the data from Marketo by passing Next page Access Token. It's working fine but the Batches jobs seem to run more than 1 hour. Marketo Access Token expires after 3599 seconds (1 hour), so it is giving me error access token expired in my debugs and can not continue to get more records from Marketo. Any workaround?

How can I do re-authentication in my batch class to get the new access token?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same method you used to get the original token, but it will only return a new token after the old one expired (a pretty bad design decision on marketo's part) http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/

Thanks!